# Crystal Reports filter parameter based on value of field

Tags: sql, parameters, filter, crystal-reports

I attempted to find something about this, but I don't feel i know the terminology well enough, and I'm not very familiar with crystal reports so maybe I missed the answer. To the point though.

I am attempting to create a dynamic parameter for a report that only displays values for records that have a a given value in a given field.

So, the way I'm thinking is

If I have a list of computernames in a database and I wanted to display only computernames of the computers containing quad core processors so when using the computername as a parameter I could display only those computers.

{?computername} = {computername} If({dbname.cores} = "quad core")

Obviously that doesn't work, or I wouldn't be asking. Anyone have thoughts on this one? Does this make any sense? I'm not most premium with the crystal reports or sql logic so I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: do you want to filter the records that dynamic paramter displays during runtime? is this your requirement?

Comment: Yes, I guess my analogy wasn't great, long day. I'd like to display only results that contain data in a given field. A better analogy would have been

   {DBname.computername} = {?computername} and
   {DBname.computertype} = "Laptop" and
   not(isnull({DBname.Owner}))

So what I'd want is to display only laptops, which is working, but then the parameter computername should only list the computer names that have non null owner fields.

Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: do you pass the exact computername? or do you need to look the name partially? is it in the query?

Comment: The computername comes from the database fine, but I can't figure out how to show only the computers with information listed in the owner field.